# Where does string-literal begin and end?

Tags: c99, string-literals

The C99 standard says the implementation limit for characters of a string literal is 4095(?).
But where exactly does a literal end and begin?

```
printf(
    "First part"
    "second part!\r\n"
    );
```

Would this be a single string literal? Or are this 2 string literals?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) 5.2.4.1 says:

> - 4095 characters in a character string literal or wide string literal (after concatenation)

The "after concatenation" refers to the concatenation of adjacent string literals that occurs in translation phase 6 (5.1.1.2).

So for purposes of the 4095-character limit, this:

```
"First part"
"second part!\r\n"
```

is a single string literal.

Note that that's a *minimum* upper bound. Implementations must permit string literals of any length up to 4095 characters; they *may* permit longer ones, and needn't impose any fixed limit at all.

It's actually more complicated than that; the standard requires an implementation to accept *one* translation unit that hits each of the limits. But in practice, you can rely on any conforming C99 compiler to permit 4095-character literals, unless your program runs into some other implementation limit.

The limit is the same in [C11](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). In C90, it was 509 characters.

Incidentally, there's unlikely to be any good reason to print "\r\n" in a `printf` call. `stdout` is a text stream, which means that the `'\n'` newline character will be translated to whatever the OS uses as an end-of-line indicator.

(N1256 is a post-C99 draft, consisting of the official C99 standard with the three Technical Corrigenda incorporated into it. N1570 is the last pre-C11 draft, and is nearly identical to the released C11 standard. The official standards are not freely available.)