# Regarding to c99, What is the definition of a logical source line?

Tags: c, c99

Imagine we write this code:

```
printf ("testtest"
    "titiritest%s",
    " test");
```

Would this be according to ISO/IEC:9899 §5.1.1.2 — 2

Be 3 different logical source lines or would it be a single one?

And is this

> 2. Each instance of a backslash character (\) immediately followed by a new-line
>   character is deleted, splicing physical source lines to form logical source lines.
>   Only the last backslash on any physical source line shall be eligible for being part
>   of such a splice. A source file that is not empty shall end in a new-line character,
>   which shall not be immediately preceded by a backslash character before any such
>   splicing takes place.

the only rule mentioned about forming logical source lines?

As regarding to the

> 5.2.4.1 Translation limits
>
> [...]
>
> — 4095 characters in a logical source line

Would mean each translation unit should not get bigger as 4095 characters, as long we dont use a `\` right before our line breaks. And I'm pretty sure, thats not what they intend to say.

So where is the piece of the definition I'm missing to lookup?

Answer (score 1):

It's three logical source lines.

Logical source lines are mostly important because macro definitions must fit into *one* logical source line; I cannot right now think of any other use for logical source lines of more than one line. To construct large string literals, you could either use logical source lines consisting of more than one physical source line (which I personally find very ugly), or relying on the fact that quoted strings will be concatenated, which is much more readable and maintainable .

Comment: So the answer on this Question I asked is wrong(http://stackoverflow.com/q/19624738/2003898)? Or do I jsut missunderstand what you are saying about constructing large string literals?